# Representing multiple dataseries with fill opacity highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to comapre multiple dataseries on highcharts with different colors but one dataseries completely overshadows the another, I want both dataseries to be visible for a better comparision.

```
$(function() {
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
rangeSelector : {
    selected : 1
        },
    title : {
        text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
        name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data : [[1146441600000,6],
                           [1146528000000,5],
                           [1146614400000,10],
                           [1146700800000,7],
                           [1146787200000,12],
                           [1147046400000,8],
                           [1147132800000,9]],
            type : 'area',
            color:'red'
        },{
            name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data : [
                                    [1146787200000,22],
                                    [1147046400000,18],
                                    [1147132800000,1]],
            type : 'area',
            color:'green'
        }]
    });
```

});

Refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swesh/ughPE/3/

Comment: Instead of `type: 'area'` use `spline` or `line`. The data points will be visible if line or spline plots are created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swesh/ughPE/3/).

Comment: I want to show area chart occupied by the curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'rgba()' as color or define it as hex and use `fillOpacity` parameter like in the example, below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ughPE/7/

Comment: How these X-Values 1146787200000, 1147046400000, 1147132800000 get converted to date? If I have say 2012-05-06 6th-may-2012 as date how it will be converted to this format or vice-versa.

Comment: You can use formatter for labels/tooltip and then use Highcharts.dateFormat() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat

Comment: Let's say if I have dates in this format, "YYYY-MM-DD", how can I get its equivalent in number like in above fiddle 1146528000000 is converted to 5th-May, how 5th-May will be translated back to that number.

Comment: You can use split() function, and Date.UTC() or Date.parse().